# Condorcet loser criterion implying majority loser criterion

Tags: voting-systems, reference-request

I know that it is perfectly clear that Condorcet loser criterion implies majority criterion. However, I am looking for a citable source that states this. Can anyone suggest something?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Wikipedia?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_winner_criterion